# Returning IEnumerable<> from WCF service causes exception: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: wcf, service, ienumerable

When I return `IEnumerable<ProgramRange>` an exception is thrown:

**The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.**

The class ProgramRange looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class ProgramRange
{
    public ProgramRange()
    {
        this.GradeVariants = new HashSet<GradeVariant>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Range { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<GradeVariant> GradeVariants { get; set; }
}
```

The collection only contains eight items, so I don't think it's the `<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />` which is often suggested.

When I fetch the data from the context I do `.ToList()` so it can't be that:

```
 public IEnumerable<ProgramRange> GetAll()
    {
        using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
        {
            return dbContext.ProgramRanges.ToList();

        }
    }
```

I've tried to add the ProgramRange class to the known types of your service in the implementation:

```
 [ServiceBehavior]
 [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ProgramRange))]
 public class ValidationService : IValidationService
```

I've tried returning several other things just to test: `ProgramRange` (works), `IEnumerable<string>` (works), `List<ProgramRange>` (does't work)

I know there are several question on the subject here on stackowerflow and I tried a lot of suggestions, but I can't get it to work.

**Edit:**

Here's the GradeVariant class:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class GradeVariant
{
    public GradeVariant()
    {
        this.GradeVariantRules = new HashSet<GradeVariantRule>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int GradeTypeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ProgramRangeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> ProgramID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> ApprenticeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> Prefix { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<bool> IV { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual GradeType GradeType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ProgramRange ProgramRange { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<GradeVariantRule> GradeVariantRules { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question and here goes:

The problem was that WCF was unable to serialize the circular reference that Entity Framework created when loading the referenced entities.

To resolve this issue, simply put

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

over the model class.

It's explained in detail here, http://www.binaryforge-software.com/wpblog/?p=129

Answer (score 2):

Edit :
You are using nullable objects, this is not allowed in a wcf service.
Add [IgnoreDataMember] in front of these members or make them not nullable to fix your issue.

---

Could you post the class GradeVariant as well? It's possible there are certain unparsable elements in that class which throw the connection was closed unexpectedly.
A few posibilities are a dictionary or nullable item.
Your test with a single ProgramRange might work because the list of GradeVariants is empty or null.

A good tip to try out is to check the inner exception of the inner exception of the inner exception....
At the end of the line it usually says something like can't parse Dictionary.

Comment: Can this be the problem even though the grade variant collection in program range is empty?

Comment: I think you're right here. The relation to GradeVariant was the problem. For now I've removed `virtual` which prevents related data to be loaded (don't know how Entity Framework works here; why virtual makes it load related data. have to ask google). Sooner or later I have to get rid of the nullable types too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If it's the serialization (which it probably is), try this more directly to see if you can find the issue:

```
try
{
    MemoryStream tempWrite = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractSerializer ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ProgramRange));
    ds.WriteObject(myProgramRangeInstance, tempWrite);

    MemoryStream tempRead = new MemoryStream(tempWrite.GetBuffer());
    ProgramRange newInstance = (ProgramRange)ds.ReadObject(tempRead);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Try that with `myProgramRangeInstance` starting out as a valid instance of your class.  That'll tell you if it's a serialization issue, and what exactly is causing it.

Right now, I'm betting on the fact that you're using a HashSet, but I really don't know.  The exception information from the above should give more information.